# How to reach other private IP's of hosts in a group ansible playbook

Tags: docker, loops, ansible, docker-volume, sshfs

I want to deploy sshfs on 2 machines using ansible.
I have the following hosts configuration:

```yaml
--- # hosts
...
        cloud:
          children:
            cloudalpine:
              hosts:
                web-alpine-1:
                  ansible_host: Public IP
                web-alpine-2:
                  ansible_host: Public IP
```

In my playbook, I want to mount an sshfs volume, but I can't seem to only reach the **OTHER** nodes private IP address.

The final configuration I want to achieve is:
web-aplpine-1 > web-alpine-2:/etc/docker/storage
web-alpine-2 > web-alpine-1:/etc/docker/storage

```yaml
--- # Playbook
...
# I want to create a playbook with an sshfs volume mount 
- name: Volume mount for docker
  docker_volume:
    volume_name: "sshvolume"
    use_ssh_client: true
    driver: vieux/sshfs
    driver_options:
    # I am using a local private key
      IdentityFile: "{{ lookup('file', ansible_ssh_private_key_file) }}"
      port: 22
    # I am able to get the machines that is running the tasks private ip in here, but I can't get the other machines one.
    # I need each to point to the others private IP address.
      sshcmd: "<username>@:{{ The other hosts Private IPv4 address }}//etc/docker/storage"
```

How should I access the other nodes IP address on each machine?

Comment: Hi, please take into consideration to mark my answer as the right one, if it helped solving your problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Khaled . Sorry for not doing that earlier, I'm a stack overflow noob :D. Done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jinja2 loop and condition:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - set_fact: 
      other_ip: "{% for host in vars['play_hosts'] %}{% if host != inventory_hostname %}{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
  - debug:
      msg: "<username>@:{{ other_ip }}//etc/docker/storage"
```

My inventory:

```yaml
test-001 # 192.168.1.24
test-002 # 192.168.1.27
```

Result:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************************************
ok: [test-001] => {
    "msg": "<username>@:192.168.1.27//etc/docker/storage"
}
ok: [test-002] => {
    "msg": "<username>@:192.168.1.24//etc/docker/storage"
}
```

To get the hostname instead of IP:

```yaml
other_ip: "{% for host in vars['play_hosts'] %}{% if host != inventory_hostname %}{{ host }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```